# ¿Cómo mostrar aleatoriamente la comida en el juego de snake c#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace snake
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int x, y;
            x = 1;
            y = 1;

            string direccion = "E";

            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            try
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n                     presiona enter");

                System.Console.ReadLine();
                for (; ; )
                {

                    switch (direccion)
                    {
                        case "S":
                            y++;
                            break;
                        case "N":
                            y--;
                            break;
                        case "E":
                            x++;
                            break;
                        case "O":
                            x--;
                            break;
                    }
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("o");

                    Thread.Sleep(90);

                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "S";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "O";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "E";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "N";
                                break;
                        }//fin del switch(key)
                    }//fin del if (console.readkeyAvailable)
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n                                     Game over");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un objeto Random para calcular de forma aleatoria la posición de la comida. Ten en cuenta que habría que evitar las posiciones ocupadas por la serpiente.

Deberías calcular una nueva posición para la comida cada vez que la posición de la cabeza de la serpiente y de la comida coincidan:

```
namespace snake
{
    struct Position
    {
        public Position(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public static Position Empty => new Position(-1, -1);
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int x, y;
            x = 1;
            y = 1;

            Position foodPosition = Position.Empty;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            string direccion = "E";

            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            try
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n                     presiona enter");

                System.Console.ReadLine();
                for (;;)
                {

                    switch (direccion)
                    {
                        case "S":
                            y++;
                            break;
                        case "N":
                            y--;
                            break;
                        case "E":
                            x++;
                            break;
                        case "O":
                            x--;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (x == foodPosition.X && y == foodPosition.Y
                        || foodPosition.Equals(Position.Empty))
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            foodPosition = new Position(rnd.Next(0, Console.WindowWidth - 1), rnd.Next(0, Console.WindowHeight - 2));
                        } while (foodPosition.X == x && foodPosition.Y == y);
                    }

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(foodPosition.X, foodPosition.Y);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("x");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("o");


                    Thread.Sleep(90);

                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "S";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "O";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "E";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "N";
                                break;
                        }//fin del switch(key)
                    }//fin del if (console.readkeyAvailable)
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n                                     Game over");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

    }
}
```